# Change CKEditor default newpage_html

Tags: ckeditor

Here's my scenario: I have CKEditor with docprops enabled and fullpage set true. With fullpage true the contentsCss does nothing, that's a "won't fix" in Trac.

I'm trying to modify the NewPage code that gets replaced. Currently (with fullpage true), this is what clicking NewPage enters:

```
<!DOCTYPE html />
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

That's great, but there is no way to edit it. Using newpage_html only enters code into the body tags, not replacing the whole thing.

I want to replace the entire code so I can declare my CSS defaults which I can't do since fullpage is enabled.

I've looked high and low and I can't find out how to modify this. I can't even find where the default code is coming from in the source code! Any help would be glorious!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use config.newpage_html (it was missing from the docs)

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
{
    fullPage : true,
    extraPlugins : 'docprops',
    newpage_html : '<!doctype html><html><head><title>My test</title>' +
        '<link href="sample.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />' +
        '</head><body>New page, type here</body></html>'
});
```

Comment: I've tested right now with the "full page" sample and it works fine, so you might be doing something wrong.

Comment: My ckeditor init has     `newpage_html : ''` in the middle of the other settings and everything but this works perfectly. I guess I'll have to create a ticket. Any idea where the default HTML is stored anyway?

Comment: Btw, I just tested it with the "full page" sample and it definitely doesn't work. I still get the basic HTML inputted. You can see it if you hit the source button.

Comment: An empty string is the default value, you can check it in the newpage plugin. You have to provide the template that you want to use

Comment: First off, thanks a lot for answering me! Now, that default value is placed between some `<html><body></body></html>` tags. I'm trying to replace the ENTIRE html>body tag, not just the default value to go between them. Those tags are not defined in the plugin, nor in any template that I can find. Where is it? I have not modified any of this!

Comment: As I said, you just have to specify there the code that you want. If you provide only partial content, then the browser will add the missing parts to make it a HTML page. Check the sample that I've added in the answer.

Comment: That worked. I was trying to use a separate file for the entire thing and it wasn't rendering properly. Cheers!

Comment: For the record, there isn't a way to actually clear it completely, is there? My trac ticket asks about clearing it as well... Damned if I do, damned if I don't.

Comment: But the browser will automatically generate a basic skeleton when you ask it to create a new document. And also the serialization done by CKEditor will try to provide you a basic valid HTML file, so unless you write something on your own, then you can't get an empty file.